# Simple QrCode in Laravel 5.3 : Call to undefined method BaconQrCode\Encoder\QrCode::generate()

Tags: laravel-5.3, qr-code

Got this when tried

> QrCode::generate('Make me into a QrCode!', public_path('images') .
>   '/qrcode.svg');

inside my controller.

I am using Laravel 5.3 and used "simplesoftwareio/simple-qrcode": "^1.5"
also done the config/app.php part for provider and alias.

Comment: do you do `use BaconQrCode\Encoder\QrCode` and  `php artisan optimize`?

Comment: After using "use SimpleSoftwareIO\QrCode\Facades\QrCode;" it working. Thank you